# How to replace cell data in hta with vbscript

Tags: database, vbscript, foxpro, hta

I'm working on a code that will display data from a database:

```
Set MyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        MyConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB="&Datei&";Exclusive=No" 
        SQL_query1 = "SELECT DOW(daaprotx.datum)As Wochentag, Count(daaprotx.datum)/COUNT(DISTINCT daaprotx.datum)As Rückgaben FROM daaprotx  WHERE  BETWEEN (daaprotx.datum, gomonth(date(), -12), daaprotx.datum)   AND(daaprotx.prottyp='1') AND(daaprotx.station='"&Station.options(Station.selectedIndex).value&"')Group by 1"

    Set rs=CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
        rs.Open SQL_query1, MyConn 
        If Err.Number <>0 Then
        MsgBox "Sie haben kein Verzeichnis ausgewählt"
        End If
        On Error Goto 0 
        str1 ="<table border=1 cellpadding=5 sortable><tr>"
    For Each field In rs.Fields
    str1 = str1 & "<th>" & field.Name & "</th>"
    Next 
    str1 = str1 & "</tr>"
     Do Until RS.EOF
     str1 = str1 & "<tr>"
     For Each field In rs.Fields
     str1 = str1 & "<td>" & Round((field.Value),2) & "</td>"

     Next
     str1 = str1 & "<tr>"
     rs.MoveNext

  Loop
  str1 = str1 & "</table>"

  MainDisplay.InnerHTML = str1


        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        MyConn.close
        Set MyConn = Nothing
```

as result I get a table with the following:

wochentag rückgaben

2         107,69

3         114,97

4         4

5         93,06

6         88,35

So, I want to change the number in cells 1,1/ 2,1/ 3,1 .. and so on in monday, tuesday and so on.

I thaught about something like: `in case of str1=2, replace str1 = monday`, but I did not found a way till now.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name (string) of the weekday, use [CDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/LIBRary/a004631y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of [DOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/LIBRary/74e4xa4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

(In the long range, you should do some research wrt displaying recordsets in HTML; your current approach is horrible.)

Comment: My problem with CDOW is that then by Group by the list will be sortet by the beginning of the letters: Friday is then first and so on. And I need the german name for the days, so I thaugt replace where the best way. That is why I'm choose this way. The hole programm is much bigger, but I have postet the relevant code.

Comment: @Crying - so use something like "SELECT CDOW() ... ORDER BY DOW()"